# Access `this` variable of parent object inside ajax

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I understand Ajax is asynchronous, but I still fail to understand how object scoping and the use of how javascript likes to use `this` works.

```
mylibrary = { 
        my_variable: 0,
        my_function: function() {
                $.ajax({
                        url: "/theinternet",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {
                                // things
                        },   
                        success: function(response) {
                                this.my_variable += 1; // How do I access my_variable?
                                console.log("HOORAY!");
                        },   
                        error: function(error) {
                                console.log("ERROR");
                        }    
                // }).bind(this); this doesn't work.
                }).bind(this);
        }   
}
```

How on earth am I suppose to access `my_variable` inside the success function of the ajax call?

It seems like this would be a pretty common thing people need to do, no?

Comment: You need to use `bind` on the function expression, not on the return value of `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the object name. Change `this.my_variable += 1;`

To

`mylibrary.my_variable += 1;`

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**
Changing `my_function: function()` to arrow function `() =>` syntax should solve the problem.

**Background**
The problem is that the value of `this` that is passed to the ajax call comes from the `my_function` and not the `my_library` object. It is because `function` always scopes their own `this`, you can use arrow function which does not yield new `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the reference of `this` in a variable outside the ajax request so that the variable can be accessed inside the ajax request. Something like this,

```
mylibrary = {
    my_variable: 0,
    my_function: function() {
      var _this = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: "/theinternet",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          // things
        },
        success: function(response) {
          _this.my_variable += 1; // How do I access my_variable?
          console.log("HOORAY!");
        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log("ERROR");
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

In this code we have `var _this = this;` where `_this` is accessible inside the `$.ajax` as that ajax request is in `my_function` and `_this` is in local scope of `my_function` which references `this`. Now when you use `_this.my_variable` it will change the `my_variable` of the object `mylibrary`

And the error in your code is that you are not binding `this` with the function. You should be doing this to get your `bind` work

```
  mylibrary = {
    my_variable: 0,
    my_function: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/theinternet",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          // things
        },
        success: function(response) {
          this.my_variable += 1; // How do I access my_variable?
          console.log("HOORAY!");
        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log("ERROR");
        }
      });
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the scope of parent Method to a variable using `let _this = this` and use it inside the inner functions.

```
 mylibrary = { 
            my_variable: 0,
            my_function: function() {
                    let _this = this;
                    $.ajax({
                            url: "/theinternet",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: {
                                    // things
                            },   
                            success: function(response) {
                                    _this.my_variable += 1; // How do I access my_variable?
                                    console.log("HOORAY!");
                            },   
                            error: function(error) {
                                    console.log("ERROR");
                            }    
                    // }).bind(this); this doesn't work.
                    }).bind(this);
            }   
    }
```